# How to depict mockups longer than the device

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mockup

just wanted to ask what would be the best way to depict screens that are longer / wider than the device itself. For example a list, that has some kind of important item at the very bottom that is off-screen normally. Should I split it up into two seperate screens, one showing two different "scroll-states"? Or rather make it one long screen? What would be the best way to go about something like that?

Comment: I think this question would be better placed at http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: You are right ... I am slowly losing track of all these Stackexchange sites :D

Comment: One popular way to do it see this image https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/1400/3c2d5c33586011.56b0c113a2963.png

Comment: Depends entirely on the purpose of the mock-up. What audience are you showing it to and for what reason?

Comment: @DA01 I am showing it to a customer but I guess it will probably also be shown to the developers later-on. It is mostly to show off the looks of the app, but it would be important to see everything since it will be a guideline for the developers, too.

At least I think so. I am just an intern :D

Comment: @Lucian ah, cool. Thanks. I will try that approach

Comment: Do you want to post your comments as answers? Or should I rather delete this thread here, since my 40 mins between posts are over now and I have the same question up on ux.stackexchange.com and I'll give you the link?